# React antd nested table and drag & drop sorting

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to integrate between the nested table and drag & drop by using antd

https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-nested-table

https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-drag-sorting

But It seems not easy (I'm a newbie on front-end using React)

Anyone can help please to make a nested table with drag & drop sorting ou

Here is the current implementation

https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-sorting-antd4121-forked-0gcuq?file=/index.js

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, I think your code is complete. The only thing which is remaining is to uncomment the call of **setData** function in **useCallback** (line 138). So that the useCallback function can update the data object according to user drag and drop

```
    const moveRow = useCallback(
    (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
      const dragRow = data[dragIndex];
      setData(
        update(data, {
          $splice: [
            [dragIndex, 1],
            [hoverIndex, 0, dragRow],
          ],
        }),
      );
    },
    [data]
  );
```

Please correct me, if I'm wrong in understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in package compatiblity

```
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "^11.0.0",
"react-dnd": "^11.0.0",
```

now code is working fine